# Silverlight and web application common library

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, asp.net-3.5

Hello I have an application that had been done on Silverlight, exist a lot of classes inside of this application. I need to create new application that should you some classes from Silverlight app. I decide make refactoring and move this classes to external library and add like reference to Silverlight and My new web site. But Silverlight doesn't allow to use normal libraries i need use just special Silverlight class library. How I can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) project

Comment: Sadly it seems like the answer is yes - it is just for .NET 4.0 and above. You can always include the files directly in different projects but I don't think this is an approach that will scale.