# Where to add the class file in silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to silverlight. I need to know where to add a class file for a silverlight application. Either in silverlight project or web project. Which is the correct way?

Comment: Then how can i access the class file in Service?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Please provide some more details

Comment: I need to create a class file in silverlight. Got two projects silverlight and Web loaded in my solution. Since both accept class file where can i now create and which is the correct way.?

Comment: Why do you think you need to access the class in both the Silverlight project and the web project?

Comment: @ChrisF For validation purposes need a class file to be accessed in silverlight project. To bind the data from SQL need a class accessed in Web project.

Comment: @ChrisF May i know where to add the class file?

Comment: You shouldn't need to access the same class in the Silverlight project and the web project. The web project is just a shell.

Comment: @ChrisF Ok. If i create a class file in silverlight project how can i access it in WCF services?

Comment: Look up RIAServices. They are basically WCF services with extra stuff for Silverlight.

Comment: @ChrisF Can i have a piece of sample code explaining this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Silverlight projcet you add your silverlight classes.
In the Web project you can add your silverlight enabled WCF sercives.

Comment: Other than the WCF which class files can be added in the Web project?

Comment: If you right click on the project and go to add new item you will see. In general you add any .aspx files or .svc files.

Answer (score 0):

please see the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799956/silverlight-and-web-application-common-library) question.

you need to create Portable Class Libraries project. this will only support in .NET Framework 4.0.